# Instagram scraping: How to get the Instagram Profile Name using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, instagram, scrape

Good afternoon,
I'm currently attempting to retrieve the following field of a certain instagram profile (the profile's name [**not the username**] as shown below the username.

Therefore, I'm looking for the code to get the field: "yereni028k" (the profile's name, that is). I do have the following code to retrieve the other data in the profile:

```
   posts = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/span[text()=" posts"]/span'))).text
    followers = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/a[text()=" followers"]/span'))).text
    following = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/a[text()=" following"]/span'))).text
name = ( ..... )  #profile's name
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have a try with below code:

```
name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".-vDIg h1"))).text

user_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "_7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl"))).text
```

Css selectors are a better way to get element.

"UPDATE"
if you wanna use Xpath then use the below code:

```
name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/h1"))).text

user_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/h2"))).text
```

Comment: The code is functional, thank you very much, Zubayer, have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

use the code as below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'followers')]/ancestor::ul/following-sibling::div/h1).text
```